Foreground service for permanent socket connection
I am currently using a service that maintains a permanent socket connection to a server.
To prevent this from being terminated by Android, I start the service as a foreground service.
With Android 14 (API 34), Google  drastically restricts the use of foreground services, my use case is no longer taken into account or is no longer permitted.
Is there any other way to create a service with a persistent socket connection?
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port), 30 * 1000);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()), 8 * 1024);
char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
int n;
while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  Writer writer = new StringWriter();
  writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
  String data = writer.toString();
  // process data
}


Have your own custom build of Android, and have this code be in a system service or standard Linux daemon.

No.  Even if you could, foreground services are not permanent, merely less likely to be killed.  There are however a variety of ways to be given occasional windows to be loaded and allowed to process, such as WorkManager and JobScheduler.  Describe to us what your usecase is and maybe we can help you find a way to do it without a permanent connection

The users of my app each use a "FRITZ!Box" Internet router. This router is also a telephone system. New landline calls can be retrieved from the Internet router via an interface using a socket connection.
I have also thought about providing a separate server that retrieves the calls from the users' Internet routers and then sends them to the app via FCM. But for data protection reasons, this is not an option. The current solution via the foreground service runs reasonably reliably. My problem is not that the service is terminated, but that Google no longer allows such services.
